# how to change the length of the default truncated content?

Tags: php, drupal

now, when on a taxonomy page, it list some part of  all  the content of  each node body content. i want to control the length of the truncated content, how do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow to Structure/Content types (`admin/structure/types`), then click `manage display` on the right of your content type, then click on `teaser` (at the right top corner, if there is no such a link you should create it by clicking on `Custom display settings` at the bottom of the page). Now all you need is to change `Trim length`'s value to whatever you want.